# A way to locate an element using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to locate an `href` element for some time now without any success.

```
String EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS_PAGE = "[ng-href=\"#/settings/notifications/48\"]";
```

The number keeps changing. Sometimes selenium is able to locate the element and press it but sometimes it's not. I noticed that the number keeps changing.

I attached 2 screenshots.

Any suggestion how to locate an element that its `href` changed on the run?

[the desired element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRXqp.png)

[image: the locator]

Comment: What have you tried "_without any success_". We could start from that... instead of trusting you and providing a complete answer based on screenshot...

Comment: sorry. i thought this forum is about helping other developers...

Comment: i used this : String EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS_PAGE = "[ng-href=\"#/settings/notifications/48\"]";

Comment: the thing is that it's always changed. now it is #/settings/notifications/19 for example

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it is indeed here to help developers... to **debug code**, but here you don't provide anything except a requirement. Show us what you have done. Please, add that information by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: To put you on the correct path, in pure HTML/JS, I would first take the closest element (div or other) that is fixed and then get the elements matching it. But the result depends on the need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use CSS selector for identification all a tags: `.t6.s10.clickable.no-underline`.
2. Then access to the needed element by using the index in the list (array).

Answer (score 1):

If this is changed dynamically you could try something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(), 'Email notification settings')]"));
```

This depends on text and it's not best practice, but it probably should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all href elements, and check its text to specific content, your occasion is `Email notification settings`. I always use this method if I can not have a clean and simply method to locate an element.

Answer (score 0):

also you can try

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Email notification settings"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these XPaths:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Email notification settings')]
```

or:

```
//a[contains(@href,'#settings/notifications/18')]
```

or:

```
//a[@href='#settings/notifications/18']
```